# The meaning of "бедный родственник"

Tags: значения, идиомы

Literally "бедный родственник" means "poor relative". But it doesn't make much sense in the following context:

> Что ты смотришь на меня **как бедный родственник**?

What does this idiom mean? And what is its origin?

Comment: In fact, an expression such as "Why are you looking at me like a poor relative?" is not all that unusual in English, and means exactly what has been given in answers to this question.

Comment: @David Do you mean "poor relation"? I see some similarity, but still they are not the same. Something can be a poor relation, as well as someone, but the Russian бедный родственник only applies to people, as far as I understand. "Why are you looking at me like a poor relative?" - perhaps, it's OK in certain contexts. If that guy has a few poor relatives and that someone is looking like one... Personally, I've never heard the idiom "poor relative" before.

Comment: In English and in this context, "relative" and "relation" would both refer to a person.  I agree that "poor relation" is more idiomatic, I should have used it in my previous comment.  I've never heard "poor relation" in this contect except for a person.

Comment: The concept of a poor relation is common in 19th century novels. Often it was a spinster who lived with her relatives and was expected to help look after the children, make herself useful around the house, and behave in a self-effacing manner.

Answer (score 6):

The phrase is actually quite close to its literal meaning. Poor relatives usually ask others in their family for support and help, so the phrase came to mean *"someone who is humiliated, dependent on others"*.

[Here](https://phraseology.academic.ru/10787/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA) is a dictionary source for you.

I do not know where specifically the phrase comes from, but Google's Ngram corpora show its usage as such:
[image: Usage of "бедный родственник"]

With the earliest result being [this almanac](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1900,cd_max:1947&lr=lang_ru) (Айдинг-гюнлер Альманах к 10-летию Туркменистана. 1924-1934. Юбилейнная комиссия ЦИК ТССР, 1934). The snippet is:

> В собственной кибитке он чувствует себя, как бедный родственник на свадьбе у богатого дяди. Может быть, в самом деле придет время, когда его посадят на женскую половину и заставят мыть посуду и месить тесто...

which translates to

> In his own yurt he feels like a poor relative at the wedding of a rich uncle. Maybe, in fact, the time will come when they put him on the female half and make him wash the dishes and knead the dough...

Answer (score 3):

The previous answer is brilliant, but I would like to add that a poor relative is also shy and humble, he just looks at you and keeps silent, sits at the corner of a table or stands in the door.